# Nocturnal Animals whose Eyes Don't Shine

Tags: zoology, vision

Are there any classes of animals which are mostly nocturnal and rely on their eyesight to a non-negligible degree whose eyes still don't shine during the night?

In other words, are there animals which have decent night vision without having a [tapetum lucidum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum)?

Comment: insects come to mind.

Comment: @John I've seen arachnids that have reflecting eyes, quite awesome.

Comment: I suspect this feature is mainly found in vertebrates (such as cats, crocodiles and bats). Try invertebrates or marine animals.